# SyndicationItem Content and Summary property in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, rss, atom-feed

Correct me if I am wrong, but it appears that the `SyndicationItem.Content` is null some times based on the feed address. When it's null, `SyndicationItem.Summary` seems to have the text of the blog post.

Is this dependent on whether the feed is `RSS` or `Atom`? I am trying to get the blog post's text irrespective of what RSS URL the user inputs.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RSS feed places it's content in the  block, that information maps to SyndicationItem.Summary.

Comment: Is this configured by the author? What's the best way of writing a generic solution that takes care of any and all the feeds in the wild?